# Problems with percent encoding and Azure BLOB DELETE?

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage

Azure is returning `404 The specified blob does not exist` when it does, I can browse to the file concerned without problems.  Indeed, the file path is generated by my script from a prior call to `https://${vault}.blob.core.windows.net/${container}?restype=container&comp=list`, therefore the BLOB absolutely 110% exists !

However a DELETE call returns 404 (you can see my header construction below, along with the Azure response) :

```
S:DELETE











x-ms-date:Tue, 09 May 2017 17:22:27 GMT
x-ms-version:2016-05-31
/myaccount/mycontainer/path/to/my/dir/Some%20File%20B_Foo_Bar%20Dev_1234.docm
S:EBHf8ElRGrAiYAbLTtYa9SqWFJ2eg7F0bebRNGTlLac=
404 The specified blob does not exist.
Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 17:22:22 GMT
Server: Windows-Azure-Blob/1.0 Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Content-Length: 215
Content-Type: application/xml
Client-Date: Tue, 09 May 2017 17:22:39 GMT
Client-Peer: 191.235.193.40:443
Client-Response-Num: 1
Client-SSL-Cert-Issuer: /C=US/ST=Washington/L=Redmond/O=Microsoft Corporation/OU=Microsoft IT/CN=Microsoft IT SSL SHA2
Client-SSL-Cert-Subject: /CN=*.blob.core.windows.net
Client-SSL-Cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384
Client-SSL-Socket-Class: IO::Socket::SSL
X-Ms-Request-Id: 5b3ddd1c-0001-00c1-10e8-c80c81000000
X-Ms-Version: 2016-05-31
```

I am using a Perl script (the script goes through the XML from the container/list API and deletes stuff older than X ) , consuming the API directly, relevant part is :

```
for my $data ( $twig->findnodes("//Blob[Properties/Last-Modified < ${then}]")) {
        ### SEND DELETES
        my $filNam=$data->field("Name");
        $hdrs = "/${vault}/${container}/${filNam}";
        my $delURL="https://${vault}.blob.core.windows.net/${container}/$filNam";
        if ($debug) {
        say "DelURL: ".$delURL;
        }
        if (!$nodelete) {
        doHTTP("DELETE",$delURL,
        $hdrs,
        encode('UTF-8',"DELETE\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\nx-ms-date:${tNow}\nx-ms-version:${azureVersion}\n${hdrs}",Encode::FB_CROAK)
        );
        }
}
```

FYI, its not my code, I get the same error if I use Microsoft's NPM client (i.e. `azure -vv storage blob delete data` .....)

Comment: Can you share the code for blob deletion? Are you using some SDK or consuming REST API directly?

Comment: @GauravMantri have updated with a code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

I think I might have found the answer.

Seems like a bit of "feature" (a.k.a. bug).

Looks like percent stuff needs to be prefixed with 25 (e.g. %20 becomes %2520).

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsazurestorage/2012/05/28/character-encoding-issues-related-to-copy-blob-api/